# Fullscreen button disabled

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm newbe in Cocoa Apps development. My `fullscreen` button is disabled for some unknown reason. Probably the problem is in `styleMask`. Here is my code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    lazy var window = NSWindow(contentRect:
        NSRect(center: NSScreen.main?.frame.center ?? .zero, size: CGSize(width: 800, height: 450)),
                               styleMask: [.titled, .miniaturizable, .closable, .fullSizeContentView],
                               backing: NSWindow.BackingStoreType.buffered,
                               defer: false)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let vc = Router.getPhotoBrowserNSViewController()
        window.contentViewController = vc
        window.delegate = NSWindowHandler()
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground  = true
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.maxFullScreenContentSize = NSScreen.main?.frame.size ?? .zero
        window.minFullScreenContentSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 450)
    }
}
```

And here is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkxIf.jpg

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the window's `collectionBehavior` to an option set that includes `.fullScreenPrimary`.